# SSRS sum max by group

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an SSRS report that looks like this (with additional columns such as sales) with rows grouped by region and location.

[image: SSRS report]

The goal for the locations is the max for each location as in my query the goal appears on each sales record that I'm summing.

```
=Max(Fields!goal.Value)
```

The goal for the regions is the sum of the max for each location in that region group.

```
=Sum(max(Fields!goal.Value, "LocationName"), "region")
```

Those first two are no problem, but I'm having difficulty getting the grand total for the report which would be the sum of each region total.

```
=Sum(Fields!goal.Value, "region")
```

I can't reference the region group as the total is outside that group - "scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function". How do I get the sum of each region (7,000) in this instance?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In both of the total textboxes, region and Grand Total, you can use the same expression:

```
=Sum(max(Fields!goal.Value, "LocationName"))
```

Because the expression is calculated in the current **Scope** of the textbox, at the *Region* Group level this will be aggregating the `Max` goal value in all *LocationName* groups in the region, and at the Grand Total level this will be aggregating the `Max` goal value in all *LocationName* groups in *all* regions.

You can see this in action. With data like:

[image]

(I've doubled up the rows to make it obvious if the end totals are correct)

and a simple table:

[image]

The same expression gives the correct result in both the *Region* and *Grand Total* **Scope**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried =Max(Fields!goal.Value) ? If you need the unscoped grand total this should work. Here is a great MSDN article on [Adding Grouping and Totals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170712.aspx). Below is an image taken from that [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170712.aspx) that shows how to set it up.

[image]

Renders:

[image]