# RDL Aggregate Distinct Field Per Group

Tags: reporting-services, aggregate, distinct, rdlc, rdl

I would like to aggregate the distinct values per group in my data.

Example:

[image]

As you can see, I am having trouble on the Aggregate column. 
The expression I'm using is `=SUM(Field3)`

Groupings: 
Parent = Key 
Child1 = Field4 
Child2 = Field5

I can see issues with what I currently have but I'm on my wit's end. I'm also unable to find a Distinct method available, only CountDistinct. Any ideas? TIA!

NOTE: I'm using SSRS 2008 on Visual Studio 2013 Update 4.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005166/ssrs-sum-max-by-group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resorted to using `Row_Number() OVER (PARTITIO BY .. GROUP BY ..) AS 'Row Number'` and added the condition that `Row Number` must be equal to `1` in order to avoid duplicate aggregation of values in my RDL expressions.